# Can you mix CodeIgniter code with non-framework code?

Tags: codeigniter

So, the situation I have is this: I am responsible for refactoring one part of a large web site. Up until recently, the site has been cobbled together by co-ops who were supervised by people who do not know web development. The resulting code is a horrible mess. I would like to start using a framework, but it is not possible to stop all other development in order to refactor the entire site and make use of CodeIgniter site-wide straight away. Instead, I would like to start by doing the work I am assigned in CodeIgniter and expand its use into other parts of the site as time and workload permit. While I am sure it is possible to do this, how difficult is it? Are there any 'gotchas' of which I need to be aware? Any insights you can offer based on your experiences are appreciated. I have done projects in CodeIgniter from the start before, and I have done projects that use no framework at all, but I have never tried to migrate a project that uses no framework to be a project that uses a framework before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've answered the question yourself. Best tip I can give you is that you'd have to heavily rely on mod_rewrite until you've recoded everything.

Comment: I will have to investigate mod_rewrite further to gain a better understanding of this as I have not made extensive use of mod_rewrite in the past. Any further information you could provide on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem before and I did it. You can do it too.

You can migrate it slowly, because its true that you can do it immediately. So, You can create CI application, and these code that you transform, to add on CI folders (like you did before), others you can let in others folders and slowly migrate in CI. You can do it without problem, because CI also transforms their code into PHP code, so it will be the same.